# Why is this error message for date in mysql arriving?

Tags: mysql

I can't insert date here. My table was:

```
CREATE TABLE salary
(
    emp_id int NOT NULL,
    basic int,
    net_salary double,
    salary_date date,
    FOREIGN KEY(emp_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
)
```

When I give:

```
INSERT INTO `salary`(`emp_id`, `basic`, `net_salary`, `salary_date`) 
VALUES (121,5000,,20190-06-21)
```

it shows an error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '20190-06-21)' at line 1

Comment: `VALUES (121, 5000, 0, 20190-06-21)` will work.

Comment: Yes, the message is on salary_date. AND yes, employee exists with that one.

Comment: And that's a very odd date.

Comment: Arulkumar, if I use 0 as third value, then there is a problem. Because, I have a VIEW for that. I have calculated 'net_salary' based on 'basic' which is in this table.

Comment: P.Salmon, that was a typo. sorry.

Comment: @UtshabKumarGhosh If  'net_salary' not allowing zero, then you need to pass the valid data or need to revise your view logic.

Comment: my view logic:
CREATE VIEW calc_salary AS
SELECT basic
FROM salary
WHERE (basic+0.45*basic-0.09*basic-0.15*basic) = net_salary

Answer (score 0):

Double data type can't be empty. You can place zero or null value for the `net_salary` column.

Also `20190-06-21` is not the valid date, is may be `2019-06-21`. The year `20190` has 5 digits.

The working query will be:

```
INSERT INTO `salary`(`emp_id`, `basic`, `net_salary`, `salary_date`) 
VALUES (121, 5000, 0, '2019-06-21')
```

or

```
INSERT INTO `salary`(`emp_id`, `basic`, `net_salary`, `salary_date`) 
VALUES (121, 5000, null, '2019-06-21')
```

Comment: thanks for the info. But what if I want to calculate the net_salary on the basis of salary = (basic*0.45) ? I have already made a VIEW like:
CREATE VIEW calc_salary AS
SELECT basic
FROM salary

Comment: @UtshabKumarGhosh That is moving the goal posts and it would be better suited for another question.This answers the original question.